# What should I name a client in ./build-key "client1"?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

When generating a key for OpenVPN client, there's this command:

```
./build-key client1
```

where I should name a client. I wonder, what should I name them? Can it be their email? Or something like `"client_#{client_id_from_db}"`?

Comment: Whatever you want so long as you can relate it to the correct client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anything that will help you identify who or what device is connected to your VPN. I usually use people names for desktop/laptop VPN client and hostname when I connect servers to the VPN.

Comment: can I rename an existing client later?